# Conditional Prompt rendering in Inquirer?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am building a command line interface in node.js using library: inquirer.

based on my need I want to render prompt, confirmation text etc when user input's. example.

## inquirer usage

```
var _questions = [{
  'type': 'list',
  'name': 'databasetype',
  'message': 'Choose database :',
  'choices': ['mongoDB', 'mysql [alpha]', 'firebase [alpha]', 'url [alpha]'],
  'default': 'mongoDB'
}, {
 'type': 'input',
 'name': 'xfactor',
 'message': 'X Factor [email, username etc..] :'
}]

// show question's.
Inquirer.prompt(_questions).then(async (__answers) => {
 console.log(__answers)
})
```

## what i want

if user chooses mongoDB than it should render another prompt asking
mongodb url

Answer (score 24):

You can use the `when` question property, its value should be a function that returns a boolean; `true` for show question, `false` for don't show question

so using your example:

```
_questions = [{
    type: 'list',
    name: 'databasetype',
    message: 'Choose database :',
    choices: ['mongoDB', 'mysql [alpha]', 'firebase [alpha]', 'url [alpha]'],
    default: 'mongoDB'
}, {
   type: 'input',
   name: 'url',
   message: 'Enter the URL',
   when: (answers) => answers.databasetype === 'mongoDB'
}]
```

see more examples here [when usage examples](https://github.com/SBoudrias/Inquirer.js/blob/master/packages/inquirer/examples/when.js)

Comment: Your answer does not seems to work with `type: 'expand'`. It doesn't prompt anything.